# Java framework for textual user interface (TUI)

Tags: java, tui

I need to create TUI for my application. Is there any framework to help me with it? I need something like [Ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), but for Java. I have found some ([Jcurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/), [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html)). Anyone have experience with them? Please, advise me, which is better (better is mean easier in my case). Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**Lanterna**](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) - Java library for creating text-based GUIs.

If you are familiar with Java's GUI frameworks like Swing or AWT, the UI-component based approach (window, panel, content-pane, add-component) might be easy to pick up.

It is used by [CHARVA](http://pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) in their GitHub repo [charva-lanterna](https://github.com/viktor-podzigun/charva-lanterna).

See also:

- Software Recommendations Stack Exchange: [user interface - A Library for text based UI with menu facility in JAVA](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82804/a-library-for-text-based-ui-with-menu-facility-in-java)